# Is there a way to enable double vectors for OpenCL on a Mac?

Tags: c++, c, macos, opencl

I'm trying to use a `double3` in OpenCL, but I get the following error:

```
error: field has incomplete type 'double3' (aka 'struct__Unsupported_Type__Do_not_use_double3_on_this_device')
```

I've presumably enabled double precision floating point data types with `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable`, but I don't know why I'm getting this.  Is this a limitation of Mac OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by having a workstation class card like in the mac pro.  On systems with consumer video cards, doubles are not available.

Your error message pretty much says it all:

```
"struct__Unsupported_Type__Do_not_use_double3_on_this_device"
```

Supporting doubles in hardware takes up space and power and is a feature that most people don't need, so most video cards don't support it and ones that do are slower doing common graphics tasks than ones with the same transistor count dedicated solely to 32-bit floats.

Here's an article on the relative double performance between workstation and consumer video cards: https://www.microway.com/knowledge-center-articles/comparison-of-nvidia-geforce-gpus-and-nvidia-tesla-gpus/

The short version is, a very expensive consumer card ($1000) gets about 10% the double performance of a high end workstation card with similar manufacturing complexity.